# Migrating current resources into reusable nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, nested-stack

I have a monolith cloudformation stack in every microservices creating the same kind of resource, I want to make it modular by breaking it into the nested stack and reusing them in each service. My understanding of nested stack is that you can use them as reusable units to create bundled resources. I am aware about the importing existing resource by setting the deletion policy to retain and importing in another stack. I am having trouble understanding how I can use the existing resources in the nested stack and also keeping it reusable. If I have import logic in the nested stack then it cannot be reused?

For example, let's say you create an EC2 instance along with cloudwatch alarms in each stack. I would like to modularize it by putting all the related resources into a nested stack called `MyEC2Stack`. I can then use `MyEC2Stack` in the parent stack to create as many resources as I want. Now my usecase is to use `MyEc2Stack` to create the resources that existed before as well as a new set of resources. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

I would look into doing this in **two stages**:

1. Create **standalone stacks** with the imported resources. You already indicated that you are aware of this. But you also should be aware that [not all resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html) can be imported.
2. In your parent stack **import the stacks** from step 1 as nested stacks. This could be possible, because you can import existing stack as a nested stack as described [Nesting an Existing Stack](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-nested-stacks.html)

Importing existing resources into CFN, is not easy. It probably will require trail-and-see approach to get it right Thus, better to **practice on some tests stacks** and resources in stead you start changing production templates.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply! I have a doubt regarding `Create standalone stacks with imported resources.` Will I be able to reuse this nested stack in other services/stacks? It feels more like just being able to break the parent stack into multiple nested stacks with importing resources but this doesn't solve the problem of using them as sharable *modules*. We have the same group of 3 resources in all the services, instead, we plan to leverage nested stacks to just created one nested stack and reuse everywhere.

Comment: @SpaceX It seems to me that maybe import/export of outputs, instead of nesting, could be better if you want to share same resource among different stacks. Have you considered that?

Comment: Sorry, I think it was not clear in my message earlier. For every microservice, we deploy it through its own cloudformation stack. Every stack has EC2, Cloudwatch alarms and other boilerplate stuff. I want to move it out to `MyEC2Stack` and want to use in all the microservices. Now if I created `MyEC2Stack` for Microservice A by importing the resources, it won'te work with Microservice B as it will have resources with different ARN. Resource type is same but resource instance is different.

Comment: @SpaceX I see. It can difficult to import all this. Have you considered re-deployment of your existing services as new once, maybe through blue/green deployment. It maybe easier that trying to figure out how to do it on existing stacks.